# python flask running in one port connected to UI running in node server different port

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask-restful

The website is running using node server. I want to create a python flask rest api to connect to pop up chat window of this website.My python flask is running in 8085 port and node server is running in 8082 port.

in python flask app.py

> @app.route('/') 
>   def hello_world():
>       return render_template('popupchat.html')
>
> @app.route('/chat',methods=["POST"]) def chat():

this popupchat.html is pointing to website pupupchat window. and there is one bind.js script having  $.post("/chat" , if i want to connect this pop up chat window running in node server to python flask server , how i will connect .

i appreciate your suggestions

Comment: how did you deploy flask?

Comment: Also please tell us more about your server environment. Especially what your constrains are.

Comment: @not_a_bot_no_really_82353 -  i have ec2 instance , ubuntu (red hat linux). I installed using sudo pip install flask. Python version is 2.7 My question is website pop up chat window is running on http:<server ip>:8082/chat.html , python flask is running on http:<server ip>:8085 . How i will connect the route so that chat window send and receive message from python flask . both have the same server only port is different.

Comment: Why is the python version 2.7? This is an deprecated version, if you are using old code this is no problem but if you are building a new system please consider python 3. Also why do you want to receive messages from flask? Don't you want the chat window to "call" flask for a service? What is your use-case?

Comment: @not_a_bot_no_really_82353- I can not install python 3, as few more applications also build on python 2.7. my use case is to build a pop up chat window in an existing application. So the UI person already created that pop up chat window. i have rasa model already build for NLU . I am thinking to build a python flask program in which i will call rasa rest api. Based on user message received , i will get the intent then do some processing and reply back to user. I am new to flask.

Comment: If this is a commercial application you can't deploy flask on it's own!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just debugging try to adjust the port on the side of the chat window. You can tell the chat window to reach a certain port by altering the url you are trying to reach. Example:
`http://your_ip:your_port/your_route` or in your case `http://your_ip:8085/your_route`

If you are already deployed please talk to your admin since this might be depending on your server.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read the flask tutorial and seek a good deployment server.